# PHP 5.5 Password_Verify Not Working while extracting data from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, passwords, verify

I intend to use `password_hash` and `password_verify` functions to store the passwords safely.

When I use the one below. That works

```
$hash = password_hash('test',PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 
$state= password_verify('test',$hash);

if($state){
    echo "OK";
}
else{
    echo "No!";
}
```

But when I try to write the password into database and get it from. It doesn't work.

```
$Pass= password_hash($pass,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$query= "INSERT INTO user(email, password) VALUES('$Email','$Pass')";
mysqli_query($link,$query);

$query= "SELECT password FROM user WHERE email='example@example.com'";
if($result=mysqli_query($link,$query)){
         $Array=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
         $isComplete=password_verify($pass,$Array[1]);  
         if($isComplete){
              echo "OK!"
         }else{
              echo "Not OK!";
         }
}
```

That's my column

[image]

Comment: Please post the code that retrieves the password from the database, too

Comment: I added database code

Answer (score 1):

The password is in `$Array[0]` not in `$Array[1]` .

But you should definitely use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to secure your application from potential SQL Injection attacks

Comment: Thanks for contribution @dimlucas but the problem is not about it. I printed Array[1] and the password is in there.

Comment: Then try changing the database's collation to 'utf8_general_ci'